# How can I use and access a struct value as a property in obj C? Getting exec bad access

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, exc-bad-access

I have the following struct

```
Helper.h

typedef struct fileInfo {
    UInt8 *fileHeaderContent;
    UInt32 fileHeaderLength;

}

typedef struct globalFileStruct {
    UInt8 *data;
    UInt32 dataLength;
    fileInfo fp;
}
```

I need to use this as a part of my singleton as follows:

```
@interface CommonFile : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, assign) globalFileStruct *gFileInfo;

@end

@implementation CommonFile

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static CommonFile *sharedInfo = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInfo = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInfo;
}

-(void)someMethod {
   CommonFile *file = [CommonFile sharedInstance];

   /* BAD ACCESS ERR */
   if( file.gFileInfo->fp.fileHeaderContent == NULL) {

        //do something
   }
}
@end
```

Like I pointed out in the code, I am getting a bad access error, I presume because gFileInfo is NULL.

My question is, What is the best way to handle this scenario? How can I ensure that the pointer object points to a variable that is real and not NULL?

I originally tried having the code be :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) globalFileStruct gFileInfo;
```

However, the problem with this was when I used it in a method as follows:

```
 file.gFileInfo->fp.fileHeaderContent = [somedata bytes]
```

I got the error : `"Expression not assignable"`

Comment: `gFileInfo` is null. You are storing a pointer to a struct. You have never given that pointer any value other than null.

Comment: You will need to `malloc` some memory for the struct and assign it to the pointer.

Comment: @Paulw11 If I did malloc in init & free in dealloc, will dealloc be automatically called when the process gets killed or should I explicitly invoke dealloc?

Comment: Since it is a singleton, it will never be deallocated, but when the app exits everything is cleaned up for you at that point.  Personally, I wouldn't use a struct like this; I would use a class and create an instance of the struct only when required (e.g. when interacting with a C function that needs the struct)

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that just a personal preference or is there a problem using it this way?

Comment: It's my personal preference based on the potential for memory leaks and pointer exceptions.  I think it generally best to minimise the use of low-level C structures

Comment: Why not to have a structure in ivar such as `globalFileStruct _gFileInfo;` and then manipulate it via accessors? If you have a pointer then you have to allocate and free memory manually. ARC won't manage structs for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 file.gFileInfo->fp.fileHeaderContent = [somedata bytes]
```

*I got the error : "Expression not assignable"*

Construct the whole struct as a local variable, replace the field and assign it to property. Structs are quite heavyweight to be passed as arguments by value though.